# Store Named Attribute Value is turned to zero?

Tags: geometry-nodes, custom-attributes

I´m trying to get to attributes from two different points to another mesh. If I´m doing this the attributes (which aren´t zero) are turned to zero. How can I use this value for another node tree?

[image]

Comment: Please present your problem in a way as clear as possible. Instead of storing multiple attributes, use just one, and spend saved space to present the entire node tree. You wouldn't want an answer to your problem to be so laconic as your question, and with redacted node tree.

Comment: The values in the first picture are moving and scaling the selected object. The attributes from the third picture are there, because I want to stretch the object between two points. My problem is that when I try do subtract the x position from the other or use even only one attribute, it is like not there (visible in picture two, the top is only one line instead of a face). @MarkusvonBroady

Comment: i think you didn't understand that you cannot use named attribute on two different trees without using sample index node. Every tree/branch has its own named attributes. But i agree to Markus, you didn't even show us your whole node tree - so we can only guess what you did.

Comment: I now added the whole node tree but how do I exactly do this with sample index? @Chris